# ARCore application doesn't work after building

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I made an app using Unity and Google ARCore. I built the app successfully ( The HelloAR example ) but when I run it on my android phone I get a black screen with a "Settings" icon on the top-right corner of the screen (camera doesn't open) and it doesn't work. So I did some debugging and this is the error I get when i run the app:

```
08-11 13:56:59.333: E/Unity(25384): ARCoreManager::FireEarlyUpdate() failed to create a shared 
secondary main thread GLES context for use with the multi-threaded renderer. 
08-11 13:56:59.333: E/Unity(25384): (Filename:  Line: 148)
08-11 13:56:59.407: E/Unity(25384): Cannot transform coordinate when native session is null. 
08-11 13:56:59.407: E/Unity(25384): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line:35)
08-11 13:56:59.409: E/Unity(25384): Cannot transform coordinate when native session is null.
```

I did some research but I can't find anything that is related to my problem. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you forgot to remove vulkan from your graphics API under player settings.

Go to Player Settings > Other Settings -> Graphics API. Select Vulkan and click on the "-" sign. This shall remove the vulkan graphics API.

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android

Comment: Thank you i actually switched to AR Foundation and my app worked fine, but i appreciate your answer and i'm accepting it.

Comment: I used ARCore plugin in Unity 2019.4.0f1 and had a similar problem. The apk was built successfully, yet in latest phones with Android 9 or more, the same error was thrown in the log during runtime. Error: _ARCoreManager::FireEarlyUpdate() failed to create a shared 
secondary main thread GLES context for use with the multi-threaded renderer._ **Removing Vulkan** from Graphics API solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the ARCore support is enabled in XR Settings and remove Vulkan Graphics API from Other Settings -> Graphics API.